# Dynamics AX Alert to a form that requires an active buffer

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax

I can easily create alerts and open make it open a form with the correct record when the user clicks on "Go to Origin".

I can't do that when the form I want to open requires an active buffer though. Inside the `init` method it checks for the correct buffer on `args()`.

My real question is:

How do I add the correct buffer to the form when creating an alert? Or should I add it on a `MenuItem`? Because as far as I know, the alert knows where to point because I provide a `MenuItem` for it. So when should I provide the correct buffer so the form can initialize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To acomplish something like this the usual pattern is to do something like the following:

```
Args args;
MyTable myTable;
MenuFunction menuFunction;

// Find the record that needs to be passed. This could also be done through a
// select or a call to any function returns a record of the type needed.
myTable = MyTable::find(123);

menuFunction = new MenuFunction(menuitemDisplayStr(MyMenuItem), MenuItemType::Display);
args = new Args();
args.record(myTable);
menuFunction.run(args);
```